# How to run multiple audio files in python scripts

Tags: python, windows-10

i have created a script in python and i wanted to run multiple audio(`.wav`) files, 4. There are repetitive statements written, for ex `os.system`, `time.sleep` appear multiple times, is there a way to run the iterations multiple times by writing them just once?

```
import os
import time

command = "cmd"

print (" Starting iteration")
print ("Clearing device logs and will start to collect New logs")
os.system (" adb logcat -c")
time.sleep(3)

os.system (r'start C:\Alexa\whatshould.wav')
time.sleep(10)

print ("Capturing logs")
os.system (" adb logcat -d -v threadtime >> what_should_i_wear_today.txt")
time.sleep(3)

os.system (r'start C:\Alexa\wakeword.wav')
time.sleep(4)

print ("Capturing logs")
os.system (" adb logcat -d -v threadtime >> wakeword.txt")
time.sleep(3)

os.system (r'start C:\Alexa\photo.wav')
time.sleep(10)

print ("Capturing logs")
os.system (" adb logcat -d -v threadtime >> photo_capture.txt")
time.sleep(3)

os.system (r'start C:\Alexa\video.wav')
time.sleep(10)

print ("Capturing logs")
os.system (" adb logcat -d -v threadtime >> Video_capture.txt")
time.sleep(3)
```

And i have created it in windows, can i use this script in other platforms like mac?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. It's time for you to learn how to use [functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to run all the tracks in a directory (`C:/Alexa`, in your case) you can use the `os.listdir()` function which returns a list of all the files in that directory.

```
import os
import time

command = "cmd"

print (" Starting iteration")
print ("Clearing device logs and will start to collect New logs")
os.system (" adb logcat -c")
time.sleep(3)


path = 'C:/Alexa/'
song_list = os.listdir(path)
song_list.sort()


for song in song_list:
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system (f'start {os.path.join(path, song)}')
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("Capturing logs")
    os.system (" adb logcat -d -v threadtime >> what_should_i_wear_today.txt")
```

Comment: This command makes all the audio files to play, is there any way to give 15seconds time interval between all the audio files?

Comment: @RoshanRaja To the best of my knowledge, `time.sleep(10)` should produce a 10 second delay in every iteration.

Comment: few audio files plays the next moment and few plays after 10 seconds. and it randomly chooses the audio file. is there a way of making it choose in order?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help 